# Clone a git repo without history and have the original repo be able to push changes to the shallow repo

Tags: git, git-clone, shallow-clone

Here's the scenario. I have a repository *A* that has a TON of history and revisions that I don't want in this other repository, *B*. How can I sync the two without moving over the entire history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can come up with is to do an archive out of *A*, and then applying that onto the new repository, *B*. This would collapse all changes into one commit which isn't ideal but might be the only way to do this.